# What's it called to be cautious about something you do?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term in English for where you want to describe the discreet or cautious approach you take, when you want to make sure you're not risking or jeopardizing anything in doing a routine job?

How would a native complete these sentences?

> The _______ is to take two more spare tyres with you when you go off-road.

OR

> You have to bring a sleeping bag, in case it gets cold in the forest over night; that is called _______, my friend :)

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to ask. What red line or threshold? What discreet/cautionary approach do you mean? And to what? And how does any kind of cautionary approach fit with the gap in your example sentence? The most obvious things I can think of to complete the sentence would be “rule”, “general guideline”, “sensible thing to do” and such things, which don’t seem to relate to the rest of your question at all.

Comment: Workplace health and safety guidelines?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't elaborate properly, I just edited the question, What about  now? @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Ah! Now it makes sense. @Julie’s comment is definitely what it most often springs from. _Procedure_ is often used in this sense (though it doesn’t imply that you’re being careful or cautious).

Comment: Well being careful is the whole point, something like a margin you sidestep to, not to risk anything. Isn't there an informal synonym for such action? @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: @MortezaFarhang Why not just use a phrase like "safest way"? Do you really need a single word for this?

Comment: NO, all the expressions are more than fine! I guess I'm just pushing to find an exact synonym of a term we say in Persian; which lot of times doesn't work between two languages, obviously. @RMac

Comment: How about the word "careful"?

Comment: The ***smart*** thing to do is to take extra tires with you when you go off-roading.  That is called ***being smart***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is ***precaution***.

*The best precaution is to take two more spare tyres with you...*

*That is precaution, my friend*.

Comment: "Precaution measure"; does that fit too? @WS2

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is [***prudent***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prudent)

Defined in the American Heritage dictionary<sup>1</sup> as:

> 1. Careful or wise in handling practical matters; exercising good judgment or common sense: *a prudent manager of money.*
> 2. Characterized by or resulting from care or wisdom in practical matters or in planning for the future: *a prudent investment.*

Your sentences would read:

> The ***prudent*** approach is to take two more spare tires with you when you go off-road.
>
> You have to bring a sleeping bag, in case it gets cold in the forest over night. That is called ***being prudent,*** my friend:)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

> The **sensible** thing is to take....
>
> That is called being **sensible**.  OR That is called having **good
>   sense**. OR That is only **common sense**.

Sensible:  Acting with or exhibiting good judgment; reasonable

Sense:  Natural understanding or intelligence, especially in practical matters: *The boy had sense and knew just what to do when he got lost.*

American Heritage, Fifth Edition, 2011

OR

> It's good **preparation** to take....
>
> That is called being **prepared**.